# Actionbar logo padding left

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

The actionbar shows a space on the left side of the logo. This space is reserved for the upindicator i think.

I want to give this space a defined distance of 20dp for example.

How can i do this?

I can set the padding of the icon to 0, but that does not remove the space between the logo and the left side of the screen.

I tried to solve it by using a custom layout. But there is a little problem. Every time the activity launches, first the normal actionbar appears and then shows the custom layout.

This is how i show my custom view:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        //set custom actionbar
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
        //Displays the custom design in the actionbar
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }
```

This is in my styles.xml:

```
        <!--Customize the actionbar-->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButton</item>

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/green2</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/app_icon_small</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->

    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/padding_border</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/padding_border</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/icon_plus</item>
        <!--<item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>-->
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    </style>
```

This is the layout of the custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/green2">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_border"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_border"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon_small"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YOLO"
        android:gravity ="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried disabling the home button?

Comment: Show some of your code.

Comment: @sureshkumar how do you do that?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo i added information to my question

Comment: using this code ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setShowHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

Comment: @sureshkumar that does not work either. The little arrow disappeared, but my logo does not move to the left, where my arrow was placed. It is just free space that i can't change

Comment: can you provide a screenshot

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, so here is a link
http://i58.tinypic.com/ddndqf.jpg

Answer (score 12):

You can create xml file(your_xml_file) in folder /res/drawable, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:right="20dp"/>


</layer-list>
```

and add it to code:

```
<activity android:name=...
            android:logo="@drawable/your_xml_file" >
```

Comment: This only adds padding to the right of the icon. I want to move the actual viewHolder of the icon to the left, and set a custom padding between the left side of the screen and the icon.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the space between the left side of the screen and the logo I used it:

```
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        </style>

        <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
            <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">-11dp</item>
        </style>
```