# Why my image on my custom Actionbar has unwanted left padding

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I customized the `ActionBar` by inflating a custom view.
and my custom action bar XML layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ab_main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="heaer_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ab_main_img0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ab_main_img_layer_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but I don't know why there is an unwanted left padding for my `ImageView` at run time!!! like image below:

[image: http://8pic.ir/images/ar3ykgqke9an68kj6hoc.png]

anybody know?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658876/actionbar-logo-padding-left check this link

Comment: solution does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you use "wrap_content" or "match_parent" in your ImageView (not TextView) on your custom action bar xml layout, you will have padding in your action bar, otherwise you don't have.

So please try changing your xml as below: setting fixed size to the ImageView (and you can also add some margin_left for a better look).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ab_main_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:text="heaer_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ab_main_img0"
       android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ab_main_img_layer_list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Just edited my answer for a more accurate explanation of the issue :). Hope it will help others as well.

Comment: No, my image not bieng scaled because i set a selector on it, so when i touch my image a dark background apear under it and i saw the left padding again!

Comment: Well, I actually tried your way, and I also had the left padding,but after looking up the tutorial below and trying what they suggested with the fixed sizes and everything, it worked for me. 
http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android
Maybe you could try as well and see what happens. It might also have something to do with the way you inflate the action bar. The dark background is probably the native actionbar.

Comment: thanks @A B, i read your link and do its script, also i do your script, both apear with no padding! so i campare "your script and link script" to my script, then i find when i use "wrap_content" or "match_parent" in ImageView i have padding otherwise has not!

Comment: Great that it worked!Could you maybe please mark my answer as correct? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

inside ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ab_main_img0"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ab_main_img_layer_list" />
```