# Decreasing space taken by navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

My action bar has navigation drawer and profile image icon.I want to decrease the space between navigation drawer icon and profile image icon but navigation drawer icon takes fixed space even if i replace it with small icon.

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

        super.onDrawerClosed(view);

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};
ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_home, null);
mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

actionbar_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tabbackground"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profileImageActionBar"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:border_width="1dp"
        app:border_color="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Home"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImageActionBar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582747/why-my-image-on-my-custom-actionbar-has-unwanted-left-padding/28584560#28584560.

Comment: @AB navigation drawer icon is not part of my custom xml

Comment: Try to reduce the left space in the profile image..

Comment: `R.drawable.ic_drawer` is navigation drawer icon

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a screenshot of how it looks like for you?

I tried this using a simple `ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar()` with a custom view like yours, and hiding icon like this `mActionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent)`, and the space between navigation drawer icon and custom view is quite ok.

Comment: i am adding navigation drawer icon in `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
` where `R.drawable.ic_drawer` is navigation drawer icon

Comment: if i set `marginLeft` of `profileImageActionBar` as negative then navigation drawer icon comes on top of the image

Comment: Yes, I know that the R.drawable.ic_drawer is the navigation drawer icon, but for me, not using a supportActionBar, I had to set the actionbar icon transperent so to hide it. But setting negative is ok, but don't decrease the space too much, so that it won't overlap.